# Errors occurred when using range-based loop with my class, "begin no matching overloaded function found"

Tags: c++, loops

I have created a class called `List` which internally use `unordered_map` but when using a range-based loop, some errors appears:

- `error C2672: 'begin': no matching overloaded function found`
- `error C2672: 'end': no matching overloaded function found`

---

```
template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class List {
private:
    // The main container
    std::unordered_map<KeyType, ValueType> m_container;
public:
    typename std::unordered_map<KeyType, ValueType>::const_iterator Beginning();
    typename std::unordered_map<KeyType, ValueType>::const_iterator End();
    //.....
};

template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
typename std::unordered_map<KeyType, ValueType>::const_iterator List<KeyType, ValueType>::Beginning() {
    return m_container.cbegin();
}
template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
typename std::unordered_map<KeyType, ValueType>::const_iterator List<KeyType, ValueType>::End() {
    return m_container.cend();
}
```

When using:

```
List<std::wstring, std::wstring> list;
list.Add(L"AKey", L"LionKing");
list.Add(L"BKey", L"Animal");
list.Add(L"CKey", L"Good");

for (auto &item : list) // The error messages appear
    cout << item.second << endl;
```

**How to resolve those problems?**

Comment: Why are you calling your iterators `Beginning` and `End` when the convention is `begin` and `end`? Follow the conventions. Don't invent your own C++. I'd strongly advise wrapping `cbegin()` and `cend()` as well using exactly the same names.

Comment: @tadman: Thank you, I thought the name didn't matter.

Comment: Oh, no, the name *very much* matters. You can't just make things up and expect the compiler to figure it out. In C++ everything must be precisely specified.

Answer (score 2):

A range-based for loop requires that either expression is valid on your `list` variable:

- `list.begin()`
- `begin(list)`

ditto for `end`

You have chosen to name the relevant functions `Beginning` and `End`, respectively.

Either rename the functions, or define free-floating `begin` and `end` functions that call through to these, like so (untested):

```
template<class... Args>
auto begin(List<Args...>&& list)
{
   return std::forward<List<Args...>>(list).Beginning();
}
```

(relevant standardese [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ranged#1.3))

Comment: Thank you, in the second case, should `begin()` function to be unrelated to a class? and how to use it in the main function?

Comment: The free function I've posted here should only be in the same namespace as `List`